# Apache SystemML scalar-martix (elementwise) multiplication not working

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, neural-network, systemml

please consider the following code:

```
  #update
  W1 = W1 - learningRate * dJdW1
  W2 = W2 - learningRate * dJdW2
```

Where learningRate is double and dJdW1/dJdW1 2d matrices.

I'm getting this error:

> ERROR: Runtime error in program block generated from statement block between lines 58 and 61 -- Error evaluating instruction: CP\xb0-*\xb0W2\xb7MATRIX\xb7DOUBLE\xb01.0E-5\xb7SCALAR\xb7DOUBLE\xb7true\xb0dJdW2\xb7MATRIX\xb7DOUBLE\xb0_mVar117\xb7MATRIX\xb7DOUBLE

EDIT 12.7.17:

plus this one...

> ordinal not in range(128)'))

The whole DML can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/romeokienzler/70b0789cae49425e44ded5963ebc8021)

The complete Error can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/romeokienzler/7b686d03126bd3f529f162e382657d49)

The whole jupyther notebook can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/romeokienzler/760f4a3879ea9d9f73cff1980e1235af)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cellwise scalar matrix operation is fine. Looking at your error, it says that your matrix/vector dimensions are not compatible:

```
 : Block sizes are not matched for binary cell operations: 3x1 vs 2x3
 org.apache.sysml.runtime.matrix.data.MatrixBlock.binaryOperations(MatrixBlock.java:2872)
 org.apache.sysml.runtime.instructions.cp.PlusMultCPInstruction.processInstruction(PlusMultCPInstruction.java:66)
 org.apache.sysml.runtime.controlprogram.ProgramBlock.executeSingleInstruction(ProgramBlock.java:290)
```

Looking at your Notebook, this comes from:

```
 W2 = W2 - learningRate * dJdW2
```

W2 is initialized W2 = rand(rows=hiddenLayerSize,cols=outputLayerSize)
as a 3x1 matrix, while dJDW2 is a 2x3 matrix.

Comment: had to change the return type from return (matrix[double] dJdW1,matrix[double] dJdW1) { to return (matrix[double] dJdW1,matrix[double] dJdW2) {